# Why do I need to enable vertex attribute when using VAO (DSA version)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently migrating a OpenGL 3.0 code to the new 4.5 way to build up a VAO (Vertex Array Object) using DSA (Direct State Access).

So all I did works, but something leave me curious. And I wonder if somebody could explain it to me.

So I use :

```
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &m_HWName);
```

... to create the VAO (instead of the glGen* flavor). Then, I link (or maybe "bind" is a more precise term) my VBO and IBO to it with :

```
GLuint bindingIndex = 0;

auto stride = static_cast< GLsizei >(m_vertexAttributesLayout.stride());

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(m_HWName, bindingIndex, m_vertexBufferObject.name(), 0, stride);

glVertexArrayElementBuffer(m_HWName, m_indexBufferObject.name());
```

Then I create a loop to declare every vertex attributes like :

```
auto relativeOffset = 0u;

for ( const auto & attribute : m_vertexAttributesLayout.getAttributes() )
{
    auto location = attribute.location();
    auto size = static_cast< GLint >(attribute.size());

    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(m_HWName, location, size, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, relativeOffset);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_HWName, location, bindingIndex);

    /* Why ?!? If I declare you above, it's because I want to use you... */
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(m_HWName, location);

    relativeOffset += attribute.size() * m_vertexAttributesLayout.typeSize();
}
```

My questions are :
- Is glEnableVertexArrayAttrib() used in the right place ?
- Should I use glDisableVertexArrayAttrib() ? And in the positive case, when ?
- And last one, why do we need to enable each vertex attribute ??? It doesn't make any sense to me, since we are declaring how the VAO is built.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it not working?

Comment: It's working, but I'm not sure about the glEnableVertexArrayAttrib() place, and if I need to use the counterpart glDisableVertexArrayAttrib(), and for learning purpose, why do we need to call it ?

Comment: I forget to mention this code is called once in my engine. I only bind the VAO and I draw my objects in the rendering loop.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans: "*Then, I link (or maybe "bind" is a more precise term)*" No, the "precise" term is "attach". Objects are *bound* only to the context; objects are *attached* to each other.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, i knew it wasn't "bind", because in OpenGL world bind mean a real thing. I speak french by the way, so I really need to use right vocabulary to understand what is behind API.

Comment: I read the dupplicate post, I still have one question, it is useful to disable something ? In which case you have to disable a vertex attribute ?